# Need help adding "Do you want to play again" statement in my program

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I'm making a Craps java program and I'm having some trouble adding a "Do you want to play again" statement at the end. If you can help me out that would be greatly appreciated! Also, the counter that I have to count how many games the user won/lost is not working properly. If you see the problem can you please tell me!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab5 {
    static int dice2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variables
        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        int numWins = 0;
        int numLosses = 0;

        //Call the welcome method
        welcome();

        //fetch random numbers

        /*
        * **************************************************************
        *welcome method
        *welcome user
        *no parameters
        *no return
        ****************************************************************
        */
    }
    public static void welcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to a Lucky (for me) Dice Game! \nFEELING LUCKY?!? Hope you brought lots of CASH!");{
        }

        int die1 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
        int die2 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
        int dice = die1 + die2;
        System.out.println("Roll: total = " + dice);
        int numWins = 0;
        int numLosses = 0;
        if (dice == 7 || dice == 11){
            System.out.println("Woah!!! With a: "+dice+ " You WIN!!!!!!!!");
            numWins++;
        }
        else if (dice == 2 || dice == 3 || dice == 12){
            System.out.println("Sorry, with a "+dice+" You lose:(");
            numLosses++;
        }

        while (dice != 0){
            int die3 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
            int die4 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
            int dice2 = die3 + die4;
            System.out.println("Roll: total = "+dice2);

            if (dice2 == 2|| dice2 == 3 || dice2 == 12){
                System.out.println("Sorry, with a "+dice2+" You lose:(");
                numLosses++;
                dice = 0;
            }
            else if (dice2 == 7 || dice2 == 11){
                System.out.println("Woah!!! With a: "+dice2+ " You WIN!!!!!!!!");
                numWins++;
                dice = 0;
            }
            {
                System.out.println("So far you have won " + numWins +
                " times and lost " + numLosses + " times, ");

                {


                }
            }
        }
}}
```

This is my output when I run it:

```
Welcome to a Lucky (for me) Dice Game! 
FEELING LUCKY?!? Hope you brought lots of CASH!
Roll: total = 2
Sorry, with a 2 You lose:(
Roll: total = 8
So far you have won 0 times and lost 1 times, 
Roll: total = 10
So far you have won 0 times and lost 1 times, 
Roll: total = 8
So far you have won 0 times and lost 1 times, 
Roll: total = 3
Sorry, with a 3 You lose:(
So far you have won 0 times and lost 2 times,
```

The counter should only be stated after the win or lose. How do I fix this?

Comment: First off you need to learn how to format and especially indent your code well as it is part of the Java language that while not important to the compiler is key to our understanding of your code now and you understanding it later. Much of a programming language's structure is to allow it to be understandable by humans. So please try fix your code. Indent all blocks 4 spaces, not randomly. All code on the same block should be indented the same. If you're serious about your question, then please be serious about communicating your code.

Comment: I'm sorry- This is my first time using Java so I'm still learning.

Comment: It's all OK, but please do fix your code now. Also, no more than one blank line in a row.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for explaining that to me! I noticed when you "tab" in eclipse it knows exactly where the line should start. That's pretty handy to know.

Comment: 1) to repeat something use a loop, such as here, a do-while loop. 2) To get user input, use your Scanner object. I'm sure that your course information shows you how to use this. 3) Then combine the two concepts, and you're on your way!

Answer (score 0):

To repeat something, use a loop, such as a while loop or a do-while loop if you're not sure how manny times you'll loop. To get user input, use a Scanner object -- which you've already imported. The do-while loop structure will be something like...

```
do {
  // code to do inside of the loop
} while (somethingIsTrue);
```

You will need to use some sentinel variable to change in the loop and then test inside of the while boolean check. It could be a String, in which case you'd use the String `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method in your while's boolean check.

So consider prompting for input at the end of the do block of code using `System.out.print(...)`, getting the input with your Scanner, and then testing that input in the while boolean test.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab5
{
    static int dice2;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        int numWins = 0;
        int numLosses = 0;

        //Call the welcome method
        //welcome();

        //fetch random numbers

        /*
        * **************************************************************
        *welcome method
        *welcome user
        *no parameters
        *no return
        ****************************************************************
        */


        while(true)
        {
            welcome();
        }

    }

    public static void welcome()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to a Lucky (for me) Dice Game! \nFEELING LUCKY?!? Hope you brought lots of CASH!");

        int die1 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
        int die2 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
        int dice = die1 + die2;

        System.out.println("Roll: total = " + dice);

        int numWins = 0;
        int numLosses = 0;

        if (dice == 7 || dice == 11)
        {
            System.out.println("Woah!!! With a: "+dice+ " You WIN!!!!!!!!");
            numWins++;
        }
        else if (dice == 2 || dice == 3 || dice == 12)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, with a "+dice+" You lose:(");
            numLosses++;
        }

        while (dice != 0)
        {
            int die3 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);
            int die4 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1);

            int dice2 = die3 + die4;

            System.out.println("Roll: total = "+dice2);

            if (dice2 == 2|| dice2 == 3 || dice2 == 12)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, with a "+dice2+" You lose:(");
                numLosses++;
                dice = 0;
            }
            else if (dice2 == 7 || dice2 == 11)
            {
                System.out.println("Woah!!! With a: "+dice2+ " You WIN!!!!!!!!");
                numWins++;
                dice = 0;
            }
            {
                System.out.println("So far you have won " + numWins +
                " times and lost " + numLosses + " times, ");

                {


                }
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("\n\nWould you like to play again?  ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String uinput = scanner.nextLine();

        if(uinput.isEmpty() || 
           uinput.equals("n") || uinput.equals("no"))
        {
            scanner.close();

            System.out.println("Goodbye.");

            return;
        }

        System.out.println();
}}
```

Comment: You're both spoon feeding the OP an answer, and also giving him a wrong answer. Please fix this by suggesting ways for him to fix it himself.